# how to get the index of an element in the selection array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

I need to get the **index** of **multiple** elements regarding to **their parent** ol. 
In the code bellow I think it should give me the same index for comments and tags as they are in the same `<ol>` but it **doesn't** happen.

```js
$('#main-form').find('form').each(function () { //foreach form in the ol tag
    var $drop_target_index = $('.drop_targets').index($(this).closest('.drop_targets'));
    console.log($(this).closest('.drop_targets'));
    console.log( $drop_target_index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-form">
        <ol class="drop_targets">
            <li><ol class="drop_targets comments">
                <li><form></form>
    
                Item 1 </li>
            </ol>
            <ol class="drop_targets tags">
                <li><form></form>
                Item 2</li>
            </ol></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

I expected
0
0
I got
0
1

Comment: Valid html requires that the only child elements of `<ol>` are `<li>` but you can nest anything in a `<li>`.

Comment: Almost correct you also need: `<ol><li><ol>` I know it kinda looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

Use `each()` with your `.drop_targets`.

```js
$('.drop_targets .drop_targets').each(function () {
  var $drop_target_index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
  console.log($drop_target_index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-form">
    <ol class="drop_targets">
        <ol class="drop_targets comments">
            <form></form>
            <form></form>
            <form></form>

            Item 1
        </ol>
        <ol class="drop_targets tags">
            <form></form>
            <form></form>
            <form></form>
            Item 2
        </ol>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need the drop_targets index regarding to its parent drop_targets

Comment: Because index starts with 0. You need to do index + 1 if you want it starts with 1. I did an update.

Comment: it gives different values for comments and tags which is wrong as both are in the same level regarding to their parent drop_targets ol

Comment: Check my last update. You don't need to get the index of `.drop_targets` children but only `.drop_targets` parent. It should be 0 0 but I think you want 1 1 as result

Answer (score 0):

Cause you use the same class name, here is sample to change second `<ol>` class to get index.

```
<div id="main-form">
<ol class="drop_targets">
    <ol class="drop_targets1 comments">
        <form></form>
        <form></form>
        <form></form>

        Item 1
    </ol>
    <ol class="drop_targets1 tags">
        <form></form>
        <form></form>
        <form></form>
        Item 2
    </ol>
</ol>
```

```
$('#main-form').find('form').each(function (i,e) { 
console.log($('.drop_targets1').index($(e).closest('.drop_targets1')));
});
```

another solution don't need to edit class name

```
    $('#main-form').find('form').each(function (i,e) { 
        console.log($($('.drop_targets')[0]).find('.drop_targets').index($(e).closest('.drop_targets')));
    });
```

Comment: I need it to be generic as I have a lot of ols  with different classes :(

Comment: I think I can't change the class name(drop_targets) and also can't use tags and comments class as they will be changed from view to another.
So If I need it to be generic I have to complete using drop_targets only class.
Your code idea is right but also my case is a little different.